# Selenium, TestNG xml file, issue in execution order if added same priority in different class files

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium WebDriver with TestNG framework. In the xml file I have called two class file containing 2 tests. I have added priority for the tests in each class. But it is always executing all the tests with same priority from different class.

Class one

```
package demo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testing1 {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("Test one");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("Test two");
    }
}
```

Class Two

```
package demo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testing2 {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void test3(){
        System.out.println("Test Three");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void test4(){
        System.out.println("Test Four");
    }

}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="CavionTestSuit">
    <test name="Testing11">
        <classes>
            <class name="demo.testing1"></class>
            <class name="demo.testing2"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here i am getting the output as:

```
Test one
Test Three
Test two
Test Four
```

How can i run tests in each class together according to the priority added. 
My expected output is:

```
Test one
Test two
Test Three
Test Four
```

If i add priority for the second class as 3 & 4 it will execute in order given in xml file. But it is not feasible for project having multiple classes and tests.

Answer (score 0):

Test execution will be takes place when the testng thread is free and it picks the test case.

In your case, the thread looks for the test cases in testing1 class and it founds a test case with priority 1, thread will get occupy with method test1, once execution of test1 is done, thread will be free and looks for another test case to execute, It founds another test case with priority 1 in testing 2 class, Hence thread occupies test3 method instead of test 2 method

**Please note that when the execution is with testng.xml, the priorty is not resticted to class level, it will be analysied overall priority, first class first priority will get executed first**

Please use below line to check the thread it is executing

```
System.out.println("Test Case three with Thread Id:- "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

For your scenario to acheive you can acheive that in two ways

-- Remove priority at test level, Then your test classes will be executed in the order.

-- Re order the test cases in testing2 class to priority 3 and priority 4

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior of TestNG. You are facing this issue as

> `@Priority` is global.

Hope this gives a clear picture of the root cause.

Solution:
`dependsOnMethods` and `dependsOnGroups` should be the preferred way to order things within a class.

For more insights and info regarding this, check the below github link of testNG.

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1324

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1309